# Can't Extract Product "href" using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract the product `href` attribute from this [pages](https://www.vidri.com.sv/catalogo/07040101/Taladros-y-atornilladores-inalambricos.html). Is there any error or maybe a block?

My code:

```py
import datetime, re, time, requests
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
    

url2 = "https://www.vidri.com.sv/catalogo/07040101/Taladros-y-atornilladores-inalambricos.html"

headers = {"User-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36 Edg/95.0.1020.40"}

r2 = requests.get(url2, headers)

soup2 = bs4(r2.content, "lxml", parse_only=None)
products_container = soup2.find("div", class_= "products__container")

for item in products_container.find_all("div", class_= "productCard"):
    for sku in item.find_all("a", href = True):
    link_list.append(sku["href"])
        link_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it work by going to: `Dev tools -> Network -> Fetch/XHR -> find an appropriate name (left tab) and click on it -> Preview (opened tab on the right)` and if there's a data you want to extract, make a request to this URL from `Headers` tab.

There you'll probably find all the needed data by calling `requests` [`.json()` method](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) which will decode JSON string to a dictionary.

[image]

---

Code and [example in the online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/BeautifullSoup-no-working-to-extract-product-href#main.py):

```py
import requests
    
# Dev tools -> Network -> Fetch/XHR -> Headers -> Request Headers (list)
headers = {
    "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",  # only this request header matter, otherwise it will throw an error
}

# https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content
response = requests.get("https://www.vidri.com.sv/catalogo/07040101/Taladros-y-atornilladores-inalambricos.html", headers=headers).json()

for result in response["articles"]["data"]:
    sku = result["sku"]
    title = result["title"]
    price = int(float(result["price"]))  # gets rid of floating number: "300.00000000"

    print(f"{sku}\n{title}\n{price}\n")


# part of the output
'''
107477
Taladro inalámbrico 1/2 pulg 20v brushless cd791d2-b3
300

127397
Taladro atornillador 3/8" inalambrico bosch gsr 12v-15 fc1
225

132423
Taladro inalámbrico 3/8 pulg 12v dcd700c2-b3
175
'''
```